# Break down json variable into individual items in an arrays

Tags: arrays, json, powershell-2.0

How would you break down the following json variable into individual items in array?

```
[  
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer1",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   },
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer2",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   },
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer3",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   }
]
```

For instance, the above would translate to an array, with the following items:

Array-item 0

```
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer1",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   }
```

Array-item 1

```
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer2",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   }
```

Array-item 2

```
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer3",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   }
```

I would like to accomplish this in Powershell 2.0 and access each one individually. So far this is what I've managed to accomplish:

```
$jsonarr = @()
$arr = (Get-Content C:\json.json| Out-String).replace("[","") -split "(})," -replace "]",""
$jsonarr += $arr[0..1] -join ""
$jsonarr += $arr[2..3] -join ""
$jsonarr += $arr[4]
```

However this is extremely inflexible, and will cease to work the minute I had another server's detail to the JSON file.

Comment: Your variable is **already** an array with three elements.

Comment: How do I access each one individually?

Comment: I've updated the question with additional information, hopefully this provides more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for PowerShell v2 you can use [Convert between PowerShell and JSON](http://powershelljson.codeplex.com/)

PS

PowerShell v3+, should be the same using the tool above:

```
$json = '[  
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer1",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   },
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer2",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   },
   {  
      "server":{  
         "name":"myUbuntuServer3",
         "imageRef":"3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
         "flavorRef":"6"
      }
   }
]'

$servers = ConvertFrom-Json $json

$servers.server.imageRef
```

returns

```
3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001
3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001
3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001
```

Also, don't forget "Get-Member"

PPS

```
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> $servers.server| where name -EQ myUbuntuServer2 

name            imageRef                             flavorRef
----            --------                             ---------
myUbuntuServer2 3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001 6        



PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> $servers.server| where name -EQ myUbuntuServer2 | select -Property flavorRef

flavorRef
---------
6
```

PPPS

also ofcourse

```
$servers.server[0]
```

you should be able to index by name also but I'm making some silly error atm

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but this is not what I am going for. Please take a look at my updated question as it provides more information.

Comment: hope this helps. if that's sorta what youre looking for I'm might try writing a bit more meaningful text in an hour or two